# In MongoDB aggregation pipeline, how to project indices of embedded array that matched?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In a mongodb aggregation pipeline, I want to `$project` the indices of an embedded array (a sub-document) that matches a previous `$match` stage.

Say, I have the following docs.

```js
{_id: '1', tags: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']},
{_id: '2', tags: ['baa', 'aaa', 'aaa']},
{_id: '3', tags: ['aac', 'cbb', 'aca']},
```

Now, if I query with `{tags: 'aaa'}`, I want to output something similar to

```js
{_id: '1', tags: [0]},
{_id: '2', tags: [1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
  { $match : {tags : 'aaa' }},
  { $unwind : { path: "$tags", includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex"}},
  { $match : {tags : 'aaa' }},
  { $group : {
      _id : '$_id',
      tags : { $push : '$arrayIndex'}
    }
  }
 ])
```

Output :

```
{ "_id" : "2", "tags" : [ NumberLong(1), NumberLong(2) ] }
{ "_id" : "1", "tags" : [ NumberLong(0) ] }
```

Another way :

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
 { $match : {tags : 'aaa' }},
 { $project  : {
    tags: {
      $filter: {
        input: {
          $zip: {
            inputs: [ "$tags", { $range: [0, { $size: "$tags" }] } ]
          }
        },
        as: "tagWithIndex",
        cond: {
          $let: {
            vars: {
              tag : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$tagWithIndex", 0 ] }
            },
            in: { $eq: [ "$$tag", 'aaa' ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
 }},
 { $unwind  : '$tags'},
 { $group : {
       _id : '$_id',
       tags  : {
          $push : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$tags", 1]}
       }
   }
 }
])
```

Output :

```
{ "_id" : "2", "tags" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : "1", "tags" : [ 0 ] }
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) over the [**`$size`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the `$tags` array to include index of the each element inside the `tags` array and then you can easily use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation to exclude the elements which do contain letter `aaa`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "tags": "aaa" }},
  { "$project": {
    "tags": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": { "$range": [0, { "$size": "$tags" }] },
            "in": {
              "string": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$tags", "$$this"] },
              "index": "$$this"
            }
          }
        },
        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.string", "aaa"] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "tags": "$tags.index" }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RnMyXSJJYvT)

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "tags": [0]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "tags": [1, 2]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for an array, you should use $in.

```
db.inventory.find( { tags: { $in: [ 'aaa' ] } } )
```

You can also write the same in the match. spelling is the same.

Will help for detail. That's what you're looking for.

Source : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

---

```
db.inventory.find( { "tags": { $in: 'aaa' } },
                  { "tags.$": 1 } )
```

This is probably what you want.

Comment: `db.inventory.find( { tags: { $in: [ 'aaa' ] } } )` will give me the first and second doc (from the docs in the question) as a whole. However, I need the indices of `tags` array that match the query.

Comment: `db.inventory.find( 
    { "tags": { $in: 'aaa' } },
    { "tags.$": 1 }
)`
This gives a list of elements of the array that matches. Not their indices. However, I need their indices.

Comment: Why do you say these one by one, my beautiful brother, exactly what you want